# Render heavy React component in the background

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a recursive component that takes a couple seconds to render because of its complexity. I inspected the DOM and it turned out the component that contains that heavy component doesn't get inserted until after it fully loads. Before that happens, the page is just blank.

```
const SomeElement = (props) => {

  // ...

  return (
    <div> // not inserted into DOM until HeavyComponent fully loads
          // expected behavior: First the Loading... label is displayed, then the contents of the HeavyComponent
          // actual behavior: not rendered until HeavyComponent renders, thus Loading... label and the component shows up at the same time
      <div>Loading...</div>
      <HeavyComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would like to display `Loading...` message when the other component loads in the background, like:

```
const [ heavyComponent, setHeavyComponent ] = useState(null);

React.asyncCreateElement(HeavyComponent, props)
  .then((loadedComponent) => {
    setHeavyComponent(loadedComponent)
  })


if (!heavyComponent) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

return <div> { heavyComponent } </div>;
```

The closest I could find is `React.lazy` and `Suspense`, but it doesn't really match my usecase - I want that `HeavyComponent` to always be always visible. Using code-splitting didn't change the behavior.

So to reiterate: Is there a way to render a heavy (not because of async, but because of its complexity) component in the background (like in a service worker)?

Comment: You said "not inserted into DOM until HeavyComponent fully loads"....is that what's *currently* happen, or what you *would like* to happen?

Comment: It is what is currently happening.

Comment: What is the nature of slowness in your heavy component, maybe you can apply some techniques like rendering a dummy loading view until it finishes job etc.

Comment: I don't get how the div that wraps doesn't render until HeavyComponent renders...is there something in the code that is intentionally causing that?  Can you create a codesandbox that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 2):

Could you not just do

```
const SomeElement = (props) => {
  const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
      setFirstRender(false);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      { firstRender && <div>Loading...</div> }
      { !firstRender && <HeavyComponent /> }
    </div>
  );
};
```

so that you get the render you want, and then once it has finished generating the heavy component will replace it?

Comment: that worked but with a little trick in my situation: set the setFirstRender in a timeout, like that: setTimeout(() => {
          setFirstRender(false);
        }, 10);